# How to setup a local mirror of eclipse artifacts for mvn tycho plugin?

Tags: maven, rcp, nexus, tycho

If this is due to a timeout, then how can I setup an internal mirror to improve performance and reduce risk of timeout

**Problem**
Maven build downloads eclipse p2 artifacts via tycho plugin and times out during the build.

```
[ERROR] Internal error: org.eclipse.tycho.core.osgitools.OsgiManifestParserException:
Exception parsing OSGi MANIFEST /opt/atlassian/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/m2repo
/p2/osgi/bundle/org.eclipse.swt/3.100.1.v4234e/org.eclipse.swt-3.100.1.v4234e.jar: 
error in opening zip file -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 3):

Nexus Pro can handle p2 repositories but I don't think Nexus OSS can.

1. Create P2 Repository in Nexus Pro (url http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/)
2. Create P2 Repository group in Nexus Pro
3. Add P2 Repository to P2 Repository group
4. Modify your settings.xml to add in a p2 mirror

The first mirror is for maven, the 2nd for tycho eclipse p2 repositories

```
    <mirrors>
      <mirror>
        <id>internal-repository</id>
        <name>Maven Repository Manager running on repo.mycompany.com</name>
        <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      </mirror>
      <mirror>
        <id>p2-repository</id>
        <name>p2 Repository mirror</name>
        <url>http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/p2groups/</url>
        <layout>p2</layout>
        <mirrorOfLayouts>p2</mirrorOfLayouts>
        <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      </mirror>
    </mirrors>
```

Comment: This works with Nexus OSS too: Sonatype open-sourced the Nexus p2 plugins a while back.  Add the [nexus-p2-bridge-plugin and nexus-p2-repository-plugin](http://repository.sonatype.org] plugins to your Nexus instance and [configure the P2 Metadata Generator and P2 Aggregator Generator capabilities](https://docs.sonatype.org/display/Nexus/Nexus+OSGi+Experimental+Features+-+P2+Repository+Plugin)

Comment: I have experienced a significant problem with Nexus (OSS 2.11.2-03) and the self-compiled p2 plug-ins. It does not seem to handle composite update sites, except for the meta data of the root composite.
If I do as suggested, and use <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>, my build will fail when trying to fetch the leaf sites from Nexus. I have tried adding them all manually, but this is not maintainable.
Is there a way to work around this? Does Nexus Pro handle it better?

Comment: What does the <layout> mean here?

Comment: many years old. So, I'm guessing but layout from be the repository format.  P2 is the layout/directory structure used.